# 3D lattice with specific vertices being indicated by spheres of a specified color

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I need to graph a 3D grid where, for tbd specific vertices I need to be able to show a sphere in a specific color. For example, show a specific diagonal in space.

Comment: Please provide more detail, including what code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
GridGraph[ConstantArray[5, 3],
 VertexStyle -> Table[Rule[i, Hue[i/125]], {i, 125}]]

GridGraph[ConstantArray[5, 3],
 VertexStyle -> Table[Rule[i, Hue[RandomReal[]]], {i, 125}]]
```

or whatever color function you need.